# How to use @DisplayName in correct way while using it in Junit5 tests?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testing, junit5

Using @DisplayName(...) is useful for simplifying while running test in IDE (e.g. IntelliJ), but what about references to the method names out of the IDE:
if the test is failing for example in Jenkins or maven, will the `@DisplayName` name be used or method name? Or depends on Jenkins, maven, etc.?

Comment: have you given it a try yourself ?

Comment: I think you should just run sample test with maven and see result.

Latest version of maven surefire plugin out original test names (not display names).